# MergeSort shows index out of bound

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, merge

I am creating a mergesort method in Java, but I can't seem to know what's wrong. I have tried .add and .set, but it doesn't seem to work. From what I can see in the debugger, the numbers are correct. Please help me!

```
mergesort(list, 0, list.size() - 1);

private void mergesort(ArrayList<Integer> list, int l, int h) {
    if (l < h) {
        int m = (l + h) / 2;
        mergesort(list, l, m);
        mergesort(list, m + 1, h);
        merge(list, l, m, h);
    }
}
```

Here is my merge method.

```
private void merge(ArrayList<Integer> list, int low, int middle, int high) {
    ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int low_end = (middle - 1);
    int tmp_pos = low;
    int num_elements = (high - low + 1);

    while ((low <= low_end) && (middle <= high)) {
        if (list.get(low) <= list.get(middle)) {
            temp.add(tmp_pos++, list.get(low++));
        }
        else {
            temp.add(tmp_pos++, list.get(middle++));
        }
    }

    while (low <= low_end) {
        temp.add(tmp_pos++, list.get(low++));
    }

    while (middle <= high) {
        temp.add(tmp_pos++, list.get(middle++));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_elements; i++) {
        list.set(high, temp.get(high));
        high--;
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Look closer. If you go out of bounds you'll be able to see this in the debugger. You could also just print the parameters to `merge`. [Here's](https://keysersblog.wordpress.com/2014/04/21/debugging-java-code-a-beginners-guide/) a short debugging tutorial I wrote. It should give you some tips.

Comment: I can't find it. I looked through the debugger and it says the bug is here on the line within the while (middle <= high), but it looks fine.

Comment: I'm assuming it's the `get`s below.

Comment: What get below? It doesn't even go into the for-loop.

Comment: On the line directly below, in the `if` statement. If e.g. `high` is larger than (length - 1) or some index is negative. You should show us the initial call to mergesort. And of course, look at what line the stack trace is pointing you to.

Comment: I added the mergesort call to the code at the top. It never goes into the if-statement either. It totally ignores the first two while-loops, but jumps into the third while-loop.

Comment: What you need to do is to identify the exact line that is causing out of bounds, and with which number. Then backtrack and find out how that number could've been generated. Personally I'd print some variables along the way, but you could also use a debugger and carefully step, but since it can't go backwards you need to be aware of what's about to happen, and what to look for. And a general tip for posting here: Always post the stack trace, and point out which line it's referring to.

Comment: I just said in the first comment which line causes it.

Comment: No you didn't. You mentioned code that exists within 2 of your while-loops, and since none of those lines accesses an array(list), they're not even causing the error. That's why I mentioned looking below, at the `get`s. This is also why we want you to post the stack trace. People often don't realise that they've misunderstood/missed something, and moving past it can cause many unnecessary hours of debugging.

Comment: I am farely new at debugging and Java, so I don't know how to show you the call stack. I know how to debug to find where the code breaks, and that's on line 22 in the merge method.

Comment: You'll see it in the console. I'm guessing you're using Eclipse. You can google around to find more info on opening perspectives and finding stack traces and such. I'm guessing line 22 is `temp.add(tmp_pos++, list.get(middle++));` which means `middle` is negative or got too big, which would mean `high` is too big.

Comment: F11 and I see nothing but the printed array (from my call).